# Null values appended into all other columns in HBASE table for matched key when writing a Dataframe that has schema of only key and 1 column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, jdbc, hbase

I am trying to update a Master table (HBASE) for only 1 column but whats happens is all other columns for the affected records are populated with null.
Is there a way to get away from this ?

Here is the sample code snippet and result that explains the problem,

`val DfEmpMaster = spark.read.format(BIGSQL).option("dbtable","EMP_MASTER_DETAIL").load()
DfEmpMaster.show()`

`+------+--------+--------+------------+
|EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|EMP_ROLE|EMP_LOCATION|
+------+--------+--------+------------+
| 13222|   Steve|     SDE|         CAN|
| 23241|  Victor|    Arch|         USA|
| 43233|   Roger|    MNGR|         USA|
| 45566|   Scott|     SDE|          UK|
| 54454|Karthick|     SDE|       India|
+------+--------+--------+------------+`

`val DfEmpRole = spark.read.format(BIGSQL).option("dbtable", "EMP_ROLE").load()
DfEmpRole.show()`

`+------+--------+
|EMP_ID|EMP_ROLE|
+------+--------+
| 45566|    ARCH|
+------+--------+`

// There is EMP_ID match in MASTER table for 45566 and when i write it, other columns in MASTER tables are populated with null

`DfEmpRole.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("EMP_MASTER_DETAIL")`

// After update

`val DfEmpMasterresult = spark.read.format(BIGSQL).option("dbtable", "EMP_MASTER_DETAIL").load()
DfEmpMasterresult.show()`

`+------+--------+--------+------------+
|EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|EMP_ROLE|EMP_LOCATION|
+------+--------+--------+------------+
| 13222|   Steve|     SDE|         CAN|
| 23241|  Victor|    Arch|         USA|
| 43233|   Roger|    MNGR|         USA|
| 45566|    null|    ARCH|        null|
| 54454|Karthick|     SDE|       India|
+------+--------+--------+------------+`

EMP_NAME and EMP_LOCATION are appended with null.

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating EMP_MASTER_DETAIL table with obtained match in EMP_ROLE? you seem to be appending EMP_ROLE to EMP_MASTER_DETAIL

Comment: Doing match from EMP_MASTER_DETAIL with EMP_ROLE table through Join and getting values in query and appending back with complete result set avoids null but in my real case it's not just 4 column in target table, it's mile long column list in target table but i just want to update 1 column in it and volume of Target table is also very huge. if something code contents that provides way of mapping dataframe column list to HBASE column list and updating only those columns without touching other columns in that row works great for me.

Comment: are your columns mostly fixed? also is EMP_ROLE table small enough to be kept in memory?

Comment: Columns are fixed. EMP_ROLE is kind of table that holds input data that needs to be processed on certain columns in Master table and number of columns in the EMP_ROLE is small. the data in EMP_ROLE contains only "changes" that needs to be processed. so volume wont be very large. if it's a changes on all records of MASTER_TABLE then EMP_ROLE table holds more no of records (that's not the real case always).